# Facebook integration with Asp .Net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, integration

I need to integrate face book with my asp .net application. Here are the steps i have followed for it.

1. I have created face-book application from face-book and got application key and secret key.
2. I have used that application key and secret key in my application.

here is my code :

But in this code,  "Session["facebook_userId"]" is always giving me null value. can you tell me the reason for this ?

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    _fbService.ApplicationKey = FACEBOOK_APPKEY;
    _fbService.Secret = FACEBOOK_SECRET;
    _fbService.IsDesktopApplication = false;

    string sessionKey = Session["facebook_session_key"] as String;        
    userId = Session["facebook_userId"] as String;

    // When the user uses the facebook login page, 
    // the redirect back here will have the auth_token in the query params
    string authToken = Request.QueryString["auth_token"];

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionKey))
    {
        _fbService.SessionKey = sessionKey;
        _fbService.UserId = userId;
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
    {
        _fbService.CreateSession(authToken);
        Session["facebook_session_key"] = _fbService.SessionKey;
        Session["facebook_userId"] = _fbService.UserId;
        Session["facebook_session_expires"] = _fbService.SessionExpires;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect(@"http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=" +
            _fbService.ApplicationKey + @"&v=1.0");
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<User> userinfo = _fbService.GetUserInfo(_fbService.UserId);
        Label1.Text = userinfo[0].FirstName + "'s favorite shops";
        Image1.ImageUrl = userinfo[0].PictureUrl.ToString();

        // Use the FacebookService Component to populate Friends
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<User> Friends = _fbService.GetFriends();
        for (int i = 0; i < Friends.Count; i++)
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(Friends[i].FirstName.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

Please help me for this !

Comment: dont know s?it about asp.net but i guess you are missing the facebook session, normaly you have to request an access_token and a user or applicaiton session to query most parts of the graphapi.  (/me for example)

Answer (score 0):

Which toolkit are you using ??

I suggest you use the facebooksdk from codeplex. And yes as Rufinus says, you will need the access_token for every request to facebook. I cannot see it anywhere in your code

Follow this link instead.. [Facebook Graph API in C#](http://facebooksdk.blogspot.com/)

Comment: I am using FacebookSDK-5.0.8.0